# Unexpected indentation errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

Pretty new to python/programming in general, been working on a script but have run into indentation errors around line `for line in csv.reader( open(filename), delimiter="\t"):` been trying a few things but could use a little help sorting it out, any ideas?

Could you explain any responses you have, helps with the learning process thank you!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
import sys
import getopt
import re

changes = {}

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument ("infile", metavar="CSV", nargs="+", type=str, help="data file") 
args = parser.parse_args()

sample_names = []

SIMILARITY_CUTOFF = 95

#
# Function that investigates the similarity between two samples. 
#
#
def similar_samples( sample_name1, sample_name2):

    combined_changes = dict()

    for change, fraction in changes[ sample_name1 ]:
        if ( change not in combined_changes):
            combined_changes[change] = []

        combined_changes[change].append(float(fraction))

    for change, fraction in changes[ sample_name2 ]:
        if ( change not in combined_changes):
            combined_changes[change] = []
        combined_changes[change].append(float(fraction))


    passed_changes = 0
    failed_changes = 0

    for change in combined_changes.keys():

        if ( len(combined_changes[ change ]) == 1):
            failed_changes +=1
            continue

        sum = 0
        count = 0
        for a in combined_changes[ change ]:

            sum += a
            count += 1

            mean = sum/ count


        for a in combined_changes[ change ]:
            if ( mean > a + 2  or mean < a - 2):
                failed_changes += 1
            else:
                passed_changes += 1


#    print "passed changes: %d, failed changes: %d" % ( passed_changes, failed_changes)


    if ( passed_changes * 100 / (passed_changes + failed_changes) > SIMILARITY_CUTOFF):
        print " vs ".join([sample_name1, sample_name2]) + " : Similar samples"
        return 1
    else:
        print " vs ".join([sample_name1, sample_name2]) + " : Different samples"
        return 0



#     print "mean %.2f \n" % ( sum/ count)






for filename in args.infile:
    sample_name = filename
    #sample_name = re.search("^(.*)\_", filename).group(1)
    changes[ sample_name ] = []
sample_names.append( sample_name )

    for line in csv.reader( open(filename), delimiter="\t"):
        for item in line[2:]:

            if not item.strip():
                continue

            item = item.split(":")
            item[1] = item[1].rstrip("%")

            changes[ sample_name].append([line[1]+item[0],item[1]])

for i in range(0, len(sample_names)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(sample_names)):

        similar = similar_samples( sample_names[ i ], sample_names[ j ])


exit()
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around the `if` condition in Python.

Comment: use pylint to detect syntax error, like this kind. E: 92, 0: unexpected indent (syntax-error)

Comment: If you get a really strange compiler error that looks like it can't come from the line it says it does, look at the previous line. Works for this, also for missing semicolons, parentheses etc in other languages.

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @lanzz: no it doesn't. Code Review is for improving code that works, not finding syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line before the one you quoted should be one indention more

> sample_names.append( sample_name )

This line I mean :)

Answer (score 2):

Indentation error.

Try indenting

```
sample_names.append( sample_name )
```

line